# DateTimeFormatter fails on milliseconds

Tags: java, datetime-format, java-time

I have a string coming from a file, that depicts the datetime. I'm trying to get the right datetime from it, like:

```
LocalDateTime.parse("20151120184616363", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS"));
```

But this gives an error: Text '20151120184616363' could not be parsed at index 0

Small changes do work, like putting a space after the days, or even the seconds.

```
LocalDateTime.parse("20151120184616 363", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss SSS"));
```

But I'd rather not do extra operations, I have to repeat it quite a bit. Can someone tell me what goes wrong in the first case?

Comment: Yes, I think you're right, thanks :)

Comment: interesting observation...